How can I retrieve the IP from in real-time to continuously and dynamically authenticate that a user is accessing a resource via that IPs?
How can I retrieve the IP address from a Windows in real time using python or PowerShell to continuously and dynamically authenticate that a user is accessing a specific resource via that IP address (it will be compared to a range of ip addresses specified by me)?    I want this information for a product I'm developing. The following is a code i tried but it work statically i want to retrieve ip dynamically.

# #Import pandas library
import pandas as pd

# Registered IP addresses
RegIPs = ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", "192.168.10.4", 
          "192.158.1.38","192.168.10.6", "192.168.0.10", "192.168.0.11", 
          "192.168.2.30", "192.168.2.31", "192.168.1.21", "192.168.1.20"]

def load_employee_info():
    try:
        employees_info = pd.read_csv('Employees_info.csv')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # If the file is not found, print an error message and return an empty data frame
        print("Error: Employees_info.csv file not found.")
        return pd.DataFrame()
    return employees_info

# Filter the dataframe to get the row with the specified user_id
def retrieve_ip_address_risk_score(user_id, rip):
    employees_info = load_employee_info()
    if employees_info.empty:
        # If the data frame is empty, return a risk level of 1 (High Risk)
        print("Error: Employees_info.csv file is empty.")
        return 1

    users = employees_info.loc[employees_info["user_id"] == user_id]

    if users.empty:
        # If the user ID is not found, print an error message and return a risk level of 1 (High Risk)
        print("Error: User ID not found.")
        return 1

    # Extract the IP address from the filtered row
    try:
        incomingIP = users["ip_address"].values[0]
    except IndexError:
        # If the IP address cannot be extracted, print an error message and return a risk level of 1 (High Risk)
        print("Error: Unable to retrieve IP address.")
        return 1

    if incomingIP != rip:
        Risk_level = 1

    else:
        Risk_level = 0.1

        # Return the Risk level
    return Risk_level
        



I tried nmap with python code but didn't work.

please indent your code correctly

What do you mean by "continuously and dynamically"? How is the user running the code from different IPs? And how could the IP change while the code is running?
